# Local user notifications not created on background fetch

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I need to create a local UserNotification every-time the application does a background fetch or does a sync with a bluetooth device. The problem is that the old Local Notifications before iOS 10 worked and now the new UserNotifications they don't work/trigger, nothing happens. Is there any solution regarding this problem?

Currently my testing code is the following:

```
    let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
        if error == nil{
            print("NOT authorized")
        }
    }
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = "MyApp"
    content.body = "oi"
    let trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger(timeInterval: 60, repeats: false)
    let notification = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: "timer", content: content, trigger: trigger)

    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(notification) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print("DID NOT CREATE NOTIFICATION")
        }else{
            print("CREATED NOTIFICATION")
        }
    }
```

extension AppDelegate: UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: > @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    completionHandler([.alert,.sound])
}

@available(iOS 10.0, *)
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, > >didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    completionHandler()

} }
```

Comment: What does "don't work" mean, exactly?

Comment: no local notification alarm is sent/triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem, I was missing the request authorisation code.

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            let center  = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()

            center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { (granted, error) in
                if error == nil{
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            UIApplication.shared.registerUserNotificationSettings(UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.sound, .alert, .badge], categories: nil))
            UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications()
        }
```